# (Beginner) While loop problem: the loop doesn't stop despite it meets condition

Tags: python-3.x

If I put in the right answer first then the loop stops right away.
However,if i put in the wrong answer first then it just keeps looping back to "Your guess: ".
Can someone explain to me why is that?

````
print("Fill in the missing word:\nSun is ---")  
right_line = "Sun is red"  
>guess = input("Your guess: ")  
guess_line = "Sun is " + guess  
while guess_line != right_line:  
        guess = input("Your guess: ")
print("You are correct! " + "The right answer is " + right_line)```
````

Comment: Hello, in your loop you forgot to construct guess_line which is needed for the while condition check. Did it help? (Add guess_line = "Sun is " + guess at the end of the loop.)

Comment: FWIW, it is easier and more robust to check the ``guess`` against ``"red"`` directly, instead of comparing a sentence containing the input against a sentence containing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you never update guess_line with the new answer. You need to do that within your while loop;

```
print("Fill in the missing word:\nSun is ---")
right_line = "Sun is red"
guess_line = ""
guess = input("Your guess: ")
while guess_line != right_line:
    guess = input("Your guess: ")
    guess_line = "Sun is " + guess
print("You are correct! " + "The right answer is " + right_line)
```